# Convert DateTime with DateTimeKind.Unspecified from utc to local

Tags: nodatime

I have a database where all dates are UTC, and the driver always sends me `DateTime` objects with `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`. I want to assume they are in UTC and convert to local time.

What is the simplest way to achieve this using NodaTime?

`Instant.FromDateTimeUtc(utcDate).InZone(localZone);` keeps complaining DateTimeKind should be Utc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're definitely using Noda Time and want a `ZonedDateTime`, you could "tell" Noda Time that you've really got a UTC value, then convert it:

```
var zoned = LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(utcDate)
                         .InZoneStrictly(DateTimeZone.Utc)
                         .WithZone(localZone);
```

Or you could just use `DateTime.SpecifyKind` to start with:

```
var utcDateTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(unspecifiedDateTime, DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

... and then use your existing code, or take Noda Time out of the picture entirely if you want.

Indeed, just `DateTime.ToLocalTime()` would be fine if you don't need Noda Time elsewhere:

```
var localDateTime = utcDateTime.ToLocalTime();
```

... the BCL will assume that an unspecified date/time *is* UTC if you call `ToLocalTime()` on it. Of course, I'd recommend using Noda Time everywhere though :)

Comment: Thanks! I actually want to use NodaTime because different users will be able to set their own timezones.

Comment: @Natan: Glad to hear it - using Noda Time is clear the Right Thing to Do :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Instant now = SystemClock.Instance.GetCurrentInstant();
                    DateTimeZone TimeZone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb.GetSystemDefault();
                    var zoned = LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(msg.MessageSentUtc)
                     .InZoneStrictly(DateTimeZone.Utc)
                     .WithZone(TimeZone);
```

Simplified...